# How to use helper class as singleton in broadcast receiver?

Tags: java, android, dagger

I want to use dagger approach to for helper classes. 
Bellow is the code i am currently using for Activity. But i am not able to understand how should i be using this for helper class.

Where helper class is called inside a receiver.

**AppComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    void inject(MyApplication app);

    @Override
    void inject(DaggerApplication instance);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

**ActivityBuilder.java**

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MainActivityModule.class)
    abstract MainActivity bindMainActivity();

}
```

**AppModule.java**

```
@Module
public abstract class AppModule {

    @Binds
    abstract Context provideContext(Application application);

}
```

**MainActivityModule.java**

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {

    @Provides
    static MainPresenter provideMainPresenter(MainView mainView) {
        return new MainPresenterImpl(mainView);
    }

    @Binds
    abstract MainView provideMainView(MainActivity mainActivity);

}
```

The above code is what i am using for activities. I am now willing to use same structure for my helper classes too. I did a plenty of research and tried some methods which were failing as my Helper class requires 2 parameter. First one is context and another is IPhoneCallReceiver. I know IPhoneCallReceiver can be accessed in `@Module` using `@Binds`, but i am having issue getting Context. Here Helper class is **CallStateHelper**

**PhoneCallReceiver.java**

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements IPhoneCallReceiver {

    CallStateHelper callStateHelper;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        callStateHelper.stateChange(intent);
    }
}
```

**CallStateHelper.java**

```
public class CallStateHelper extends PhoneStateListener {

    private IPhoneCallReceiver receiver;

    public CallStateHelper(Context context, IPhoneCallReceiver receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(this, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    }
}
```

I want to use CallStateHelper by `@Inject` and want it as `Singleton` Class. I am very new to Dagger

Comment: `Context` really isn't an issue, you bind your `application` so it's available. What is `BroadcastReceiver implements IPhoneCallReceiver` though? If you register it in the manifest you will have a hard time providing `IPhoneCallReceiver` in the `@Singleton` scope. Also you have a circular dependency between `IPhoneCallReceiver` and `CallStateHelper`

Comment: @DavidMedenjak yeah `BroadcastReceiver ` goes to `Manifest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it.
You just have to provide `DispatchingAndroidInjector<BroadcastReceiver>`